# C# Tessnet2 OCR not returning the correct values atall

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ocr, tesseract

Ok so I have spent the best part of today trying to even get ocr to work properly and it is no longer crashing but when I give it a file containing text rather that just numbers a lot of weird text is pumped out...

Source code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using tessnet2;

namespace OCRTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var image = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\OCRTest\testimage.jpg");
                var ocr = new Tesseract();
                ocr.Init(@"C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\OCRTest\tessdata", "eng", true);
                var result = ocr.DoOCR(image, Rectangle.Empty);
                foreach (Word word in result)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", word.Confidence, word.Text);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Like I said I am using tessnet2 along with the eng tessdata.

When I input this image:

[image: Test data image]

I get this response from the program:

[image: Result from program]

Thanks in advance for any help or links to further tutorials you may have - I followed [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/How-to-use-Tessnet2-library-716be12f) tutorial to get thus far.. Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue - I did a stupid and set the last parameter of ocr.Init() to true rather than false...